# Topology of complement of affine variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am studying the paper of Dimca and Papadima [Hypersurface complements, Milnor fibers and higer homotopy groups of arrangements](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v158-n2-p03.pdf) and try do use the their techniques in order to study some topological properties of the complement manifold of toric arrangements.

However, I have some basic questions in complex algebraic geometry. In particular, I would like to better understand the relationship between the complement manifold of a hypersurface in the projective space and the complement manifold of its affine part. To be more specific, here is my question.

**Question**
Let $F\in\mathbb{C}[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n}]$ be a homogeneous polynomial and let $M(F)$ be the complement manifold of the hypersurface $\{F=0\}$ in the complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^{n}$. Let $M(F)_{a}$ be the complement manifold in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ of the affine part of $F$. How the topology of $M(F)$ and $M(F)_{a}$ are related?

Comment: You might want to flag @AlexSuciu.

Comment: Trivial remark: if $D_+(x_i)$ is the affine part $\mathbb C^n$ corresponding to $x_i \neq 0$, then $D_+(F) \cap D_+(x_i) = D_+(F \cdot x_i)$. Thus, it is given by the complement of the (reducible) hypersurface $V(F \cdot x_i)$.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at how $\pi_{1}(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^{2}\setminus C)$ depends on the geometry of the curve $C$. If the curve is smooth then the fundamental group is a cyclic group (depending on the degree of the curve). If we allow singularities then it is much more complicated and infinite groups appear.